# silverstripe shortcode return dynamic template

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I followed this instruction to be able to include a variable in the Content Field (HTMLEditor) of a Page - so that the variable can be replaced with other content:
http://www.balbuss.com/mini-introduction-to-shortcodes/

I want to display a list of dataobjects within the $Content.

Sadly the DummyHandler in the instruction is static. So I can´t access the Controller in it, to let him do something (generate the list.)

Is there a solution to access the controller in a static function or maybe is there another better way to put a variable in the $Content.

Thx,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller::curr() is probably what you are after?
To use in conjunction with Controller::hasCurr(), as no controller would mean an error when using Controller::curr()

See https://github.com/silverstripe/sapphire/blob/3.0/control/Controller.php#L384